# gojs find link with 'from' or 'to'

Tags: gojs

I need to find and modify link with 'from' or 'to'.
For example i have 4 node key and i need to get all link connected to their node.

```
{ "class": "GraphLinksModel",
  "copiesArrays": true,
  "nodeCategoryProperty": "shape",
  "linkLabelKeysProperty": "labelKeys",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":"e9bc2374-67ec-46d5-b973-fc9d58f05ca5", "shape":"FEMALE"},
{"key":"6597a4dd-f3b2-4ba3-9fb9-782c29f84071", "shape":"FEMALE"},
{"key":"b94c6c98-e556-4417-8ef3-b21f5cc144f9", "shape":"MALE"},
{"key":"93928089-7d09-456e-a386-b0ab0eec87a7", "shape":"MALE"},
{"shape":"LinkLabel", "key":-5}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":"b94c6c98-e556-4417-8ef3-b21f5cc144f9", "to":"6597a4dd-f3b2-4ba3-9fb9-782c29f84071", "labelKeys":[ -5 ], "category":"Marriage"},
{"from":-5, "to":"e9bc2374-67ec-46d5-b973-fc9d58f05ca5"},
{"from":-5, "to":"93928089-7d09-456e-a386-b0ab0eec87a7"}
 ]}
```

How i can find this links ?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes have several methods for this: [findLinksConnected](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#findLinksConnected), [findLinksOutOf](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#findLinksOutOf), [findLinksInto](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#findLinksInto)

To get a reference to a node you can call `myDiagram.findNodeForKey(someKey)`.

Comment: this add one more step . is any way to access to link without find Node ? because i have link from key or to key

Comment: You can look through all links. myDiagram.links.each(function(l) { if (l.fromNode.key === ...) [...] });